# pass function as parameter in cuda with static pointers

Tags: cuda, parameter-passing

I have a shortcode as bellow. I want to call a device function from the global function as a parameter.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cublas_v2.h>

// functions
__device__ void foo(int i);
__device__ void bar(int i);

// function type
typedef void(*FunctionCallback)(int);


__device__ void call1(FunctionCallback funcx)
{
    funcx(2);
}

__global__ void call2(FunctionCallback func[])
{
    call1(func[1]);
}

// Static pointers to device functions
__device__  FunctionCallback   pfunctions0 = foo;
__device__  FunctionCallback   pfunctions1 = bar;

int main(void)
{
    // host functions
    FunctionCallback  h_functions0;
    FunctionCallback  h_functions1;

    //copy device function pointer to host side
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_functions0, pfunctions0, sizeof(FunctionCallback));
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_functions1, pfunctions1, sizeof(FunctionCallback));

    FunctionCallback d_function[] = { h_functions0 , h_functions1 };


    // call function
    call2 << <1, 1 >> >(d_function);

    return 0;
}

__device__ void foo(int i)
{
    printf("In foo() with: %i", i);
}

__device__ void bar(int i)
{
    printf("In bar() with: %i", i);
}
```

But I have nothing in the result. The program should be print

```
In bar() with:2
```

I try to figure out my problem but I can't know what I did wrong, please help me.

Comment: What happens if you add `cudaDeviceSynchronize();` after the `call2<<<1, 1>>>(d_function);` line in `main`?

Comment: Thank you, I got nothing prints in the windows. I think my problem is pass function in call2. But I don't know how to fix this. If my code run only host site the code work perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have an array d_function of device function pointers, but this array is in host memory - you have to copy it to the device to be able to use it from the kernel.

This code works as expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>


// functions
__device__ void foo(int i);
__device__ void bar(int i);

// function type
typedef void(*FunctionCallback)(int);


__device__ void call1(FunctionCallback funcx)
{
    funcx(2);
}

__global__ void call2(FunctionCallback func[])
{
    call1(func[1]);
}

// Static pointers to device functions
__device__  FunctionCallback   pfunctions0 = foo;
__device__  FunctionCallback   pfunctions1 = bar;

int main(void)
{
    // host functions
    FunctionCallback  h_functions0;
    FunctionCallback  h_functions1;

    //copy device function pointer to host side
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_functions0, pfunctions0, sizeof(FunctionCallback));
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&h_functions1, pfunctions1, sizeof(FunctionCallback));

    // host array of device pointers
    FunctionCallback h_function[] = { h_functions0 , h_functions1 };
    // device array of device pointers
    FunctionCallback *d_function;
    cudaMalloc(&d_function, 2 * sizeof(FunctionCallback));
    cudaMemcpy(d_function, h_function, 2 * sizeof(FunctionCallback),
               cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    // call function
    call2 << <1, 1 >> >(d_function);

    cudaFree(d_function);
    return 0;
}

__device__ void foo(int i)
{
    printf("In foo() with: %i", i);
}

__device__ void bar(int i)
{
    printf("In bar() with: %i", i);
}
```